# Swift/Xcode error "Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope"

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting this error when truing to use FirebaseAuth in swift.
I have imported necessary models but the error keeps happening.

*"Cannot find type 'FirebaseAuth' in scope"*

```
import Foundation
import Firebase




class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUsser: User?   
}
```

Any ideas was going on?
I have restarted xcode and made sure all dependencies are up to date.